# "Since" at the end of a sentence

Tags: prepositions, adverbs, grammar-myths

I am confused with this and rarely see **since** put at the end of a sentence:

> There were the children to consider. She had told him she wanted a
>   divorce two days ago, and neither of them had slept **since**.

Can **since** be put at the end?

Comment: As to "be put", "put" is used as a past participle there. Compare, "Can the car be driven now?" http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/past_participles.htm

Answer (score 7):

It means that neither of them had slept since whatever happened in the first part of the sentence - in this case, her telling him she wanted a divorce.

Comment: Can you add some example sentence with "since" at the end?

Comment: OK: In 1965 I tasted real espresso coffee, and I haven't drunk instant since.

Comment: Or: Mary phoned me to say she was getting on the train, and I haven't heard from her since.

Comment: Isn't this usage really just a contraction of "since then"?

Comment: @JeffY, I nearly added that these sentences *could* be seen as missing a final 'then', standing in for the time mentioned in the previous clause.  I thought I'd be over-complicating it, but on reflexion it's worth adding.

Comment: @user152424 you *have* an example sentence with "since" at the end. Have you read your own question? It's right in there.

Answer (score 2):

It is just a matter of reordering the words in the sentence. The following sentence is not really different in meaning:

> Neither of them had slept since she had told him she wanted a divorce two days ago.

However, this sentence is more focused on "Neither of them had slept", while the sentence in the question is more focused on "She wanted a divorce two days ago", which is probably more important.

Comment: Hi, wythagoras, you need to change "he" to "she" after since in the quote.

Comment: It's not just a matter of reordering, because the original is actually a compound sentence.

Comment: So you come to the conclusion that the meaning *is* different, after all. And as Jeff points out, the syntactical structure is not remotely similar. So, how is this still "just a matter of reordering", then? It is not just a matter of reordering on any level or by any stretch of imagination.

Answer (score 1):

The word 'since' can act as a preposition or a conjunction (also an adverb). In your sentence:

> "She had told him she wanted a divorce two days ago, and neither of them had slept since."

'Since' is simply a preposition, linking the dependent clause:

> "... , and neither of them had slept since."

back to the independent clause you started the sentence with:

> "She had told him she wanted a divorce two days ago ..."

Maybe you are more familiar with 'since' as a conjunction? In which case the sentence would have read:

"Neither of them had slept since [conjunction] she had told him she wanted a divorce two days ago."

Note: Ignore any silly rule you may have heard that tells you not to end sentences with prepositions. It's [bunkum](http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2011/11/grammar-myths-prepositions/).