# "Since" vs "since then" at the end of a sentence

Tags: prepositions, adverbs

Related to this question: ["Since" at the end of a sentence](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/76649/since-at-the-end-of-a-sentence) where it was stated that *since* can be used at the end of a sentence:

> There were the children to consider. She had told him she wanted a divorce two days ago, and neither of them had slept **since**.

Is the above prefered over:

> There were the children to consider. She had told him she wanted a divorce two days ago, and neither of them had slept **since then**.

Does it depende on the context, or are they equally valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering a similar pair of examples from here,

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/since

I think there's a slight difference: technically, in version 1 'since' refers to an event (since she told him) while 'since then' refers to 'two days ago' (since that time). Reference to the event (*since*) in this particular sentence sounds more logical than to a recent day (*since then*).

Comment: Thank you Alex!